# WEBrick jar library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, webrick

Is there a default folder where WEBrick will search for jars when running JRuby on Rails in it? (something like the lib folder in Tomcat?)

Now I need to require all jars if running in WEBrick. In Tomcat I don't need to do this (I just need to put all my jars in the WEB-INF\lib folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no such thing to my knowledge with WEBrick - it's basically the very same ruby code with JRuby as it is with MRI ... 
you seem to be ready for using Trinidad - it's similar to ruby servers such as WEBrick (startable from the CLI: `cd myRailsApp; trinidad`) but is actually a wrapped Tomcat.

put the jars into say **myRailsApp/lib/java** and run with `trinidad --jars lib/java`
you can configure this with `config/trinidad.yml` so that you do not have to pass it every time.

I think it defaults to `--lib lib` thus putting jars directly into lib folder should work by default ...

as for the WEBrick, you can make an "auto-loaded" jar directory yourself, say you put your jars into **myRailsApp/lib/java** and then load them in an initializer, with something like :

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/lib/java/*.jar").each do |jar|
  require jar
end
```